# How do I prove the statement "If det() = 7, then  = 0 has only the trivial solution"?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-rank

Statement: `If det() = 7, then  = 0 has only the trivial solution`

We can prove that the matrix A is invertible if Ax=0 has only a trivial solution in terms of:
"Invertible only if the trivial solution is the only element of the null space" by utilizing the
rank-nullity theorem.

If A is invertible, it is full rank
Rank(A) + Nullity(A) = dim A
The null space is the set of vectors x s.t. Ax=0

Now, how can I apply the same logic in terms of the statement above, and how can I prove if it is indeed true or false?

Comment: $A$ is invertible iff $\det A\neq 0$ iff $Ax=0\implies x=0$.

Comment: If $\det A=7$, then $\det A\neq0$ and so $A$ is invertible. Hence $A^{-1}Ax=A^{-1}0$, so $Ix=0$, so $x=0$.

Comment: Actually, for a field $F$ of characteristic $7$ this is not true. Then $\det(A)=7=0$, so that $A$ has a nontrivial kernel. If your context is, say, coding theory, then this is a likely to happen.

Comment: We can "convert" $A$ to Diagonal Matrix $D$ where the Product of Diagonal elements is the Determinant 7. This will "convert" even $x$ to $y$. When "converting" , the 0 will remain 0. [[ Converting is via "Standard" row transformations & column transformations , using additions & scalar multiplications only ]] Here , $Dy=0$ will give Element-By-Element Equations of [[ Non-Zero Elements of $D$ times Elements of $y$ being Equal to 0 ]] which naturally means that all elements of $y$ have to be 0 , which in turn means that all elements of $x$ have be 0 too. Thus $x=0$ is the Solution.

Comment: @Joe just to clarify for my confusion since I am not sure on its verdict. Since det A=7 , then detA≠0, and moving along, we got x = 0. Does this mean that the statement above is really true or false?

Comment: @Prem - scalar multiplications change the determinant. It will no longer be $7$. This doesn't invalidate your argument, but you do need to modify it.

Comment: Nice Catch ! We Start with Determinant 7 & the various transformations change that to something else. Hence, towards the End, when we have the Diagonal Matrix, we multiply the "rows" by the necessary amounts to get $[7,1,1,\cdots,1,1]$ where Determinant is again 7. @PaulSinclair

Comment: @Prem - that would only work if your previous actions didn't change the determinant to $0$. But please note that maintaining a determinant of $7$ is not the requirement. The requirement is to show that $\ker A = \{0\}$.

Comment: @RalphHenry: It means the statement above is really true, since "$Ax=0$ only has a trivial solution" by definition means "the only solution of $Ax=0$ is $x=0$", which is what my computation shows.